# Updating span font in media query (without !important operator)

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

I have been using WordPress Additional CSS tool to alias and update photo elements to create a mobile responsive webpage. I've attempted the same approach for resizing text, but I cannot access the span font size specifications within my class. Other similar questions on this forum recommend adding the !important operator to the font size argument, but this does not work. How can I update the font size in the span?

For the attached image

- A: My testing space for the media query. clientName is the alias on the textbox within the WP container. I know I can alias at higher levels, but let's start here. With the original font size at 24 (see highlight C), you can see the page is not responding to the specification for size 10pt (ignore that it says 10px in the image; still doesn't respond when typo is fixed).
- B: Details for the class
- C: Details for the font-size in the span within the class div

[image]

Comment: Potential solution, but I'll leave the question open in case there's an alternative way: alias each text span (~10 on the page) with a class name. This works but only if I also use the !important classifier in the font specification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Because of the inline CSS you need to use !important

```
.clientName span{
font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

Or

```
.clientName>wbp_wrapper>h2>span{
font-size: 10px !important;
}
```